# Constructing an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Given a data table like:

```
+-----+-------------+--------+
| id  | end         | status |
+-----+-------------+--------+
| a   | 07-FEB-2018 | 1      |
| a   | 08-FEB-2018 | 2      |
| a   | 08-FEB-2018 | 3      |
| b   | 06-MAR-2018 | 2      |
| b   | 08-SEP-2018 | 3      |
+-----+-------------+--------+
```

In Oracle SQL is it possible to construct a query that would return, for each id, the minimum status for the maximum end date (there may be multiple rows with the same maximum end date).

So in this example, this would be returned :

```
+-----+--------+
| id  | status |
+-----+--------+
| a   | 2      |
| b   | 3      |
+-----+--------+
```

I've been looking at FIRST_VALUE and PARTITION BY, but I'm struggling to understand how they work and if they're what I need anyway and as a result I'm not really getting anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Give a proper title to the question that indicates the problem. "Constructing a query"  is too general.

Comment: If you can suggest a better title, I will happily change it (if I can).  Part of the problem was not knowing the technical name for what I was trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by end desc, status asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can do this with aggregation functions as well:

```
select id,
       min(status) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc, status asc) as status
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: You do not need to order by `status` in the `min ... keep` query as the `min(status)` part is already performing the same function.

Comment: Thanks! I went with the second option, which works a treat

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join othe max end

```
select m.id, min(m.status)
from my_table m
inner join ( 
select id, max(end) max_end
from my_table  
group by id ) t.max_end = m.end   and t.id = m.id 
group by m.id
```